# how to remove old image when user upload a new one - symfony2

Tags: image, symfony, upload

I'm doing the administration of an entity that have a image field.
I've followed the Lifecycle Callbacks, but I have a problem: when I edit an existing object, and I change the image, the old image remains on the server.
How can I delete it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to [unlink](http://php.net/manual/de/function.unlink.php) the file.

Before uploading take the current filename and delete them. You could do that in the set funktion for the name or the uplload function. You should do that before you overwrite the global variable for the name.

Comment: Thanks!! I've checked, in the PreUpload function, is the file exists, and if is true, I've deleted it. Thanks again!